# unable to run mongod on custom Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb

I've a device, which is running with linux kernel version 2.6. I've copied Linux 32 bit binaries of mongodb into /usr/local/bin. When I run mongod I get following output

```
./mongod: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

The output for mongo is

```
 /usr/local/bin # ./mongo
 ./mongo: line 1:ELFPª: not found
 ./mongo: line 2: syntax error: unexpected ")"
```

Can anyone tell me What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the binaries copied to the device are intended for the architecture of the device?

Comment: Yes, the device is 32 bit architecture and tried with 32bit Linux binaries.

Comment: That error looks more like something you'd receive from a shell script or JS interpreter, not a compiled program. Is that the actual output from executing `/usr/local/bin/mongod` on the command line?

Comment: Yes it is same when running as /usr/local/bin/mongod: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the binary is corrupted or it is being interpreted by your shell rather than executing. I can achieve similar output if I force shell interpretation:

```
$ sh /usr/bin/mongod
/usr/bin/mongod: 2: /usr/bin/mongod: E: not found
/usr/bin/mongod: 3: /usr/bin/mongod: �BA��RƄ,@�@@: not found
/usr/bin/mongod: 4: /usr/bin/mongod: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
/usr/bin/mongod: 1: /usr/bin/mongod: �P�x@�4�: not found
/usr/bin/mongod: 2: /usr/bin/mongod: E�@E��: not found
/usr/bin/mongod: 2: /usr/bin/mongod: cq�1A�A�: not found
/usr/bin/mongod: 1: /usr/bin/mongod: cannot create ��Q@�/�@8: Directory nonexistent
/usr/bin/mongod: 1: /usr/bin/mongod: ELF: not found
```

If you're concerned that it may be a corrupted download, you could consult [this list](http://dl.mongodb.org/dl/linux/i686), which contain md5 hashes for each MongoDB binary release (for the 32bit i686 platform). Alternatively, you could attempt installing MongoDB via a package manager if possible.

Comment: Is there any way we can stop forcing from shell interpretation

Comment: I haven't a clue what might be causing this behavior, but I'd start by trying to reproduce it in other shells or users (new accounts with blank profiles) on your system.

Comment: The most likely cause is that it was downloaded in a way that corrupted the file.  Downloads in text mode, or in a mode that does CR/NL mapping, has been known to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error when I was installing a 64 bit mongodb on a 32 bit ubuntu linux box. It went away when I installed the 32 bit package.